# Error while creating trigger using PL/SQL block

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

Question:
fl_schedule(flno, departs, dtime, arrives, atime, price).

Create a trigger to allow insertion or updation only if Flight number CX­7520 is scheduled on Tuesday, Friday and Sunday.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER flightsch_day
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON fl_schedule
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.flno LIKE 'CX7520')
DECLARE 
    day NUMBER;
BEGIN
    day:=EXTRACT(weekday FROM :NEW.departs);
    IF day NOT IN(0,2,5) THEN  
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'Flight number CX­7520 can be scheduled only on Tuesday, Friday and Sunday.');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

ERRORS:

```
SQL> SHOW ERRORS;
Errors for TRIGGER FLIGHTSCH_DAY:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
4/10     PLS-00122: FROM as separator is allowed only with specific
         built-in functions
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to be able to use `WHEN (NEW.flno = 'CX7520')` after `FOR EACH ROW`,  `UPDATE OF flno` is needed for individual column `flno`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER flightsch_day
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF flno ON fl_schedule
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.flno = 'CX7520')
DECLARE 
BEGIN
 IF TO_CHAR(:NEW.departs,'Dy','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English') NOT IN ('Tue','Fri','Sun') THEN  
     RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'Flight number CX­7520 can be scheduled only on Tuesday, Friday and Sunday.');
 END IF;
END;
/
```

**or** without that `WHEN..`  clause, take `:NEW.flno = 'CX7520'` into `IF` Statement :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER flightsch_day
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON fl_schedule
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
BEGIN
 IF NOT ( TO_CHAR(:NEW.departs,'Dy','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English') IN ('Tue','Fri','Sun')
              AND :NEW.flno = 'CX7520' ) THEN  
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'Flight number CX­7520 can be scheduled only on Tuesday, Friday and Sunday.');
 END IF;
END;
/
```

- use day abbreviations containing `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` option.
  Otherwise you can meet the unexpected situations.
- displayed error stems from use of `weekday` within `EXTRACT()` function where use of `day`, `month`, `year` allowed for a date type variable, also `hour`, `minute`, `second` ..etc. if it's a datetime type variable is allowed, but **not** `weekday`